# Menu dinâmico com JSF e Primefaces, quando fica responsivo não funciona

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java

Tenho um menu dinâmico em meu site, que é trazido através de categorias cadastradas previamente no banco de dados. Dentro de cada categoria, possui uma lista de subcategorias.

Quando eu clico em uma subcategoria, ele teria que me trazer as lojas relacionadas aquela subcategoria. Até então está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema ocorre quando eu diminuo o tamanho da tela, e ele gera esse menu na lateral, aquele menu oculto, que você clica e ele expande. Quando ele está dessa maneira, ele simplesmente para de funcionar, porém basta voltar ao tamanho normal a tela, que o menu volta a funcionar normal. Ele só não funciona quando está em alguma tela pequena.

Podem conferir ao vivo em www.portalbid.com.br (seleciona uma categoria na pagina inicial que vai aparecer o menu)

segue o código:

```
 <nav id="nav">
                    <ul id="menuvert">

                        <ui:repeat value="#{categoriaBean.todasCategorias}" var="categoria" varStatus="status">
                            <li>
                                <p:commandLink>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{categoria.titulo}"/>
                                </p:commandLink>

                                <ul>

                                    <ui:repeat value="#{categoria.subCategorias}" var="sub">

                                        <li>
                                            <p:commandLink styleClass="featured"
                                                           action="#{lojistaBean.redirSubLojas}">
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{sub}"
                                                                             target="#{lojistaBean.subCategoriaSelecionada}"/>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{sub.descricao}"/>
                                            </p:commandLink>
                                        </li>

                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </ul>

                            </li>


                        </ui:repeat>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma mão? Estou usando JSF 2.2.13 e Primefaces 6.0